# J2ME - LWUIT Java runtime exception - You must include the platform port before the LWUIT in the classpath>

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, runtimeexception

Before you ask, yes I did see and try the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510986/you-must-include-the-platform-port-before-the-lwuit-in-the-classpath-runtime-exc) here already.

But it didn't work. I keep getting the error. "You must include the platform port before the LWUIT in the classpath."

I am using Netbeans, JDK 1.6 (though J2ME isn't concerned with that I think) and I'm compiling to the Blackberry.

On a co-worker's PC, the app is compiling and running just fine. I checked everything, and every configuration of his matches mine. I even checked the order of the libraries' import.
I compiled them in order of dependency just like the solution mentioned (all libraries, not just the LWUIT ones) but I still keep getting this error.

Comment: I usually create blackberry project for LWUIT from the resource editor, "Generate Netbeans Project", and then just add my own files to it. You can give this a try if it is being problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is the correct answer, review your classpath carefully and make sure that LWUIT is before the LWUIT4IO.

I suggest migrating to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) where this just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project properties and include all optional packages and then give it a try.